# Create button with size as enum props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an enum with values:

```
enum BUTTON_SIZE {
    large = 'large',
    medium = 'medium',
    small = 'small',
}
```

and a type:

```
type ButtonSizeProps = {
    size: BUTTON_SIZE | 'large';
};
```

And I want to display a button size based on the prop that I pass:

```
export const ButtomComponent = ({ size }: ButtonSizeProps) => {
    return (
        <Pressable onPress={() => {}}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View
                    style={[
                        styles.layout,
                        size.large && { paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 40 },
                        size.medium && { paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20 },
                        size.small && {
                            paddingTop: 5,
                            paddingBottom: 6,
                            paddingHorizontal: 10,
                        },
```

Any tips on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain in your question what is the expected result and what spesifically is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, so I had to create the type like this

```
type ButtonSizeType= {
  [key in BUTTON_SIZE ]: string;
};
```

Then use the ButtonSizeType as type when passing the size of the button.